# exec not working after using "find ... -exec grep -L"

Tags: unix, grep, find, exec

I can use an exec chain like that :

```
find -name 'file' -exec grep -l 'content' '{}' \; -exec cp '{}' '{}'_copy \;
```

But using the grep -L option (L for files without match), the second exec is not executed. Why ?

```
find -name 'file' -exec grep -L 'conXent' '{}' \; -exec cp '{}' '{}'_copy \;
```

Both commands retrieve the same file. But the "exec cp" only works with the grep -l .

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so you want to do something to all those files not containing `conXent`?

Comment: yes. But why is it not working with grep -L ? The output is the same before using exec cp

Comment: OH! it works with '+' instead of '\;' , like this : find -name 'file' -exec grep -L 'conXent' '{}' + -exec cp '{}' '{}'_copy \;          But why ?

Comment: From `man find` --> `-exec command ;` ---> `The specified  command  is run once for each matched file.`. But it is still not clear, do you want to copy all files or just those matching through `-L`?

Comment: I want to copy all files without 'conXent', so all files outputed with find grep -L.    See my previous comment, it's working with '+'.

Comment: It is a bit tricky and unsafe. I would go for something like `find -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; if [ -n "$(grep -L 3 $f)" ]; then cp $f ${f}_copy; fi' {} \;`.

Comment: thanks... I'll try to understand your command , since + was working for cp, but not for sed :(

Comment: Can someone explain me how to you use sed after "grep -L" ?

Comment: Do not expand `{}` into a script block directly. Pass it as an argument to the script instead.

Comment: I don't understand Etan. A simple example  ?

Comment: See my answer for where your `find` commands were going wrong. You don't need the `-exec sh` solution here.

Comment: With '+' instead of '\;', finally it works also with 'sed'  :  find -name 'file' -exec grep -L 'conXent' '{}' + -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' '{}' \;             (don't forget '-i' !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `grep -L` is exiting with a return code of `1` for some reason. I can't explain why it is doing that though. My understanding is that it shouldn't be doing that because lines are being output.

In any case that exit status causes the `-exec` to evaluate to `false` and causes `find` to stop processing the file (the same as any other failing test does).

This doesn't happen with `+` because when `find` gives `grep` multiple files at once at least one is matching those contents so `grep` exits with a zero return code (but that's obviously not reliable here). I also cannot explain this behavior this seems exactly backwards to me also.

I believe using `-not -exec grep -L ... \;` will do what you want but I'd have to think about that a bit more to be sure.

Hm... I suppose the return codes make sense in that when the filename is output no matching lines were found and when the filename is not output matching lines were found.

Comment: I was also stumbling through this return code of `1` from `grep -L`. Weird, isn't it? That's why I ended up thinking on using `-exec sh -c` and there act accordingly. Good explanation!

Comment: @fedorqui It does make some sense even if it complicates the model I had for what grep return codes meant. The way no arguments/`-l`, `-L` and `-v` work is a bit more complicated in terms of return code then I'd assumed.